# IE11 - Attribute tab missing in new F12 Developer Tools

Tags: html, attributes, ie11-developer-tools

I'm using the re-designed IE.11 F12 Developers Tools, from April 2015.

In the past I have mostly used to tool to grab attribute details. Such as 'id', text, href. All of which were lifted from the html and represented on the right hand window in an easy to read list of name & value.

In the recent release of the Developer Tools I can see DOM Explorer and in the right hand window Styles/Computed/Layout. 
But I can't see any 'id' or text type attributes.

Where have MS hidden the attributes?
Or do I just need to dig in the html now?

Comment: upvoted. i too can't seem to find it and it is very annoying.